# Проверить наличие значения в массиве

Tags: операторы, массивы, php, if

Есть в массиве

```
$country = array('RU','AM','UA','BY');
$country1 = "RU";
```

Как мне прогнать их в оператор, чтобы сверить есть ли в массиве `$country1`.

```
$country = array(RU,AM,UA,BY,KZ);
$key = array_search($country_code, $country,true);
echo $key;
if (!isset($key)) {
echo "Ваша страна не входит список разрешенных!";
}
else { echo "все верно!";}
```

что то как то оно бажно работает меняю $country_code он все равно запоминает что до этого было

Comment: выражайтесь проще. вам нужно array_search(); ?

Comment: ну и что не так ? http://ideone.com/Fybf3J  причем тут вообще isset?

Comment: @big-vl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Чарли и велосипедная фабрика, блин

```
if (in_array($country, array('RU', 'AM', 'UA', 'BY',), true)) {
    // anything you wish
}
```

Comment: Вопрос риторический: а зачем строгая проверка типов?

Comment: @MasterAlex, а) в переменных часто приходит совсем не то, что хотелось бы, и хочется вылавливать это ближе к тем метам, где произошла ошибка б) я долбанутый и мне проще все писать по-строгому вместо того, чтобы сразу взять строгий язык

    $country = true;

    if (in_array($country, array('RU', 'AM', 'UA', 'BY',))) {
        echo 'Oh my god, it\'s a lion, get in the car! >:3', PHP_EOL;
    }

Comment: @Etki, спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$country = array('RU','AM','UA','BY');
$country1 = 'RU';
for ($a=0; $a < count($country) ; $a++) { 
    if ($country[$a]===$country1) {
        echo "Есть страна";
    }
}
```